# Writing user entered text (input) back into it's document (in mongo)

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor template rendering a document comming out of mongo db.
Parts of the document are editable (they render as html input elements).
Now I need the data to flow back into the document (and into mongo),

What is the best way to do this ?

The answer is easy if I want to write back the value of doc.a :

`doc = {a: "hello"}`

it is less easy with : doc.a[0].z

`doc = {a: [{z: "hello"}]}`

because in order to do the update, the path must be remembered
in order to write the update statement.
Updating the whole document whenever a field changes looks simple,
but inefficient...

It is an extremely common use case, some frameworks (EmberJs) have 
magical bindings that modifies the model whenever the widget's value
changes.

How is this done in meteor ?

Comment: Making this easier is on [Meteor's roadmap](https://trello.com/card/easy-forms/508721606e02bb9d570016ae/8) (and that link mentions some user-contributed forms packages as well).

Answer (score 2):

As you point out, it would probably be inefficient to run a db update command whenever the input changes.  This is especially true for draggable elements like sliders.

One thing you can do is separate the db query into a function, and then debounce it using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org), like so (untested):

```
var debouncedUpdate = _.debounce(function(newObject) {
    CollectionName.update({_id: newObject._id},newObject);
},300,true);

Template.objectInput.events({
    'keydown #text-input': function(event) {
        var newValue = $(this.find('#text-input')).val();
        var self = this;
        self.value = newValue;
        debouncedUpdate(self);
    }, 
});
```